# Outlook crash when Outlook Connectors Hotmail reminders appear

Tags: microsoft-outlook, hotmail

I'm using the Outlook connector plugin to retrieve Hotmail emails to Outlook. Recently I started seeing the following issue.

- Outlook starts
- I see the connector signing in
- As soon as it's signed in, the reminders box appears with a title claiming there are 3 reminders, but the reminders dialog box is empty (just white). At this point, Windows reports that the application has crashed. Here are the details of the crash:

  ```
      Problem signature:
        Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
        Application Name: OUTLOOK.EXE
        Application Version:  11.0.5510.0
        Application Timestamp:    3f1380f0
        Fault Module Name:    StackHash_156c
        Fault Module Version: 6.1.7601.17725
        Fault Module Timestamp:   4ec49b8f
        Exception Code:   c0000374
        Exception Offset: 000ce6c3
        OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.1
        Locale ID:    2057
        Additional Information 1: 156c
        Additional Information 2: 156c33dec5130f8dfd833ed9048ed55c
        Additional Information 3: 3b47
        Additional Information 4: 3b47119363498386791238e3432351df

      Read our privacy statement online:
        http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409

      If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy statement offline:
        C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt
  ```

I've tried starting Outlook with the `/cleanreminders` parameter, but I suspect that this isn't working because the reminders are in Hotmail, not Outlook itself.

Any hints on how to remove the reminders, or why they're causing Outlook to crash?

Answer (score 0):

Go to hotmail(in browser) and try deleting any reminders if present.

If it does not work out, delete hotmail account from outlook, reinstall hotmail connector for outlook, check for reminders in hotmail through browser and reconfigure hotmail in outlook.

Reason behind crash seems there is something fishy with those reminders. So, get rid of them.

Comment: I should have said I have already tried those steps. There are no reminders in Hotmail calendar, and I have uninstalled and reinstalled the connector. Outlook did not crash when the connector was removed.

Comment: Try this macro to remove reminders that are not appearing in calender: http://www.legacycode.net/2010/08/27/outlook-vba-remove-reminders/